# Responsive menu CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with responsive menu. It is working only when i use in @media property height: 500px; it doesn't work with auto. Why?

Here is the adress tomy test website:

http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/

when i set the height property in @media to auto the block below overlaps the menu.

Can someone please help.

Here is my HTML code: 
http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/_pages/codehtml.txt

Here is my CSS code:
in the comment

Thank you for paitience.

Comment: please show your relevant code directly in the question

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @phpWarrior — http://i.imgur.com/1d717Yv.png — Pay attention to the things highlighted by blue arrows.

Comment: http://test.warrior.ayz.pl/_css/_styles/wpstyles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you change `height to auto` block below overlaps the menu because `ul.menu-top li` has no height.

change this to

```
ul.menu-top li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #333333;
}
```

Comment: but is this in @media or normal CSS?

Comment: you have made ul.menu-top li {float:none} @media.so please change that and make height:500px to height:auto

Comment: Thank you Amal. You have saved my day (-:

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

@phpWarrior please check your code as I see your code you did not add `display: block` property on hover.

Add below code on your CSS.

```
ul.menu-top > li{
   positon: relative;
}
ul.menu-top-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#dropdown-toggle:hover .menu-top-dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: the menu has to be clickable so :hover would not help;

Comment: it doesn't because i have a special reset.css file that adds tchem. At the very begining of the document.

Comment: in this particular case jQuery does the thing for me.